# Sinkhorn algorithm doesn't converge

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, machine-learning, linear-programming

I'm trying to implement regularized sinkhorn algorithm (Wilson 62) that computes optimal transport between two uniform distribution (lat,lon). The basic idea is fixed point iteration. If you don't know this you may look at http://www.numerical-tours.com/matlab/optimaltransp_5_entropic/ mine is exactly the same.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster.hierarchical import AgglomerativeClustering
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
import shapefile
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inst = pd.read_csv('inst.csv', encoding='utf-8')[['lat', 'lng']]
    ht = pd.read_csv('ht.csv', encoding='utf-8')[['lat', 'lng']]

for k in range(0,4):
    print('k = {}'.format(k))
    gamma = 0.5
    M = pairwise_distances(inst[['lat','lng']],ht[['lat','lng']])
    K = np.exp(-M/0.5)
    N1 = len(inst)
    N2 = len(ht)
    v = np.ones((N1,1))
    i = 0
    M = 99999
    a = np.divide(np.ones((N2,1)),N2)
    b = np.divide(np.ones((N1,1)),N1)
    while i<M:
        print('i = {}'.format(i))
        u = np.divide(a,np.dot(K.T,v))
        v = np.divide(b,np.dot(K,u))
        i = i+1
    print('cluster {} has wassersetein distance {}'.format(k,np.sum(np.multiply(np.dot(np.dot(np.diagflat(u),K.T),np.diagflat(v)),M).reshape(-1,1))))
```

The final distance blows up and always equals the number of iteration. What's wrong with my algorithm?

`cluster 2 has wassersetein distance 99999.0`

I tried the library. Doesn't work, too.

```
for k in range(0,4):

N1 = len(inst)
N2 = len(ht)
b = np.divide(np.ones((N2,1)),N2)
a = np.divide(np.ones((N1,1)),N1)
M = ot.dist(inst[inst.lb==k][['lat','lng']],ht[ht.lb==k][['lat','lng']])
print(ot.sinkhorn2(a,b,M,1e-3))
```

gives broadcast gin error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (132,1) (2011,93)
```

Comment: error line pls?

Comment: `np.divide(a,k*v)` thanks

Comment: @monotonic Do you by any chance come from a Matlab background, assuming that the `*` operator performs a dot product? This is not the case with numpy where `K * v` results in a matrix. Now you try to divide vector `a` by that matrix, which is not a valid operation.

Comment: I do actually. Looks like a lot to learn. I fixed this issue but the algorithm still have some problem. If you can see any implementation of this algorithm that is wrong, please feel free to point out.

Comment: I don't think Sinkhorn distance is supposed to converge, if by convergence you mean that if the source and target histograms are identical the Sinkhorn distance should equal 0. that's why they introduced the Sinkhorn divergence instead